# Custom URL / Apache URL Rewriting

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I can't seem to get my regex working properly.

This works fine:

`RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?customURL=$1 [NC,L]`

But there's some mistakes. For one, the `$1` is alphanumeric, not just numbers (it still works, though). Also, I don't want `profile/` in the URL anymore.

I tried this:

`RewriteRule ^(/^\w+$/)/?$ profile.php?customURL=$1 [NC,L]`

But it didn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to embed a regex inside another? I don't think that works. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ profile.php?customURL=$1 [NC,L]
```

We select 1 or more word characters from the start of the string to the end, optionally terminated by a `/`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I should really do another regex tutorial, but this is the only one I need in my current project, and I'm up to my armpits in APIs!